# Showing an NSSharingServicePicker on MouseUp

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm adding sharing to my app (targeting Mavericks, 10.9), which I want to work like this:

1. User clicks Share button
2. Cursor changes to crosshair
3. User drags selection of what he'd like to share
4. NSSharingServicePicker displays, allowing the user to pick the service to share with

I'm accomplishing this using the `-mouseDown:`, `-mouseDragged:`, and `-mouseUp:` events. `mouseDown` begins the selection, `mouseDragged` provides feedback as to the area being selected, and then `mouseUp` completes the drag, showing the picker. Each time, though, I get this written to the console:

```
2014-06-25 00:13:45.111 App[31401:303] Warning: -[NSSharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect: ofView: preferredEdge:] should not be called on mouseUp
Please configure the sender with -[NSControl sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];
```

I don't understand why that would be a problem, unless you were showing it from a button click on mouse up. Should I ignore the message? I've tried showing it using `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_after` to try and get it to run outside the event's invocation, but they didn't work. I suppose I could ignore it, but does that leave the door to deprecation open?

Comment: I am getting the same warning. Did you ever find a solution or found out why it would be a problem to show the NSSharingServicePicker on mouseUp?

Comment: @massimobio nope, sorry. It's still an open question, though I haven't checked with the later SDKs.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'm still seeing it in Xcode 7b6. I guess I'll ignore it for now.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a year late but,
I had the same problem. After some research, I cam back with this answer. Before I implemented this code, my button would spin for a while, and then return with the same error you had. When I click my share button now, it no longer lags, and does not return any error. Insert this into your app's `awakeFromNib` method:`[yourShareButtonName sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];`.
This is what your code should look like:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [yourShareButtonName sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Insert the button name of your share button where it says `yourShareButtonName`

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but it doesn't apply in my case. I'm not showing the share sheet immediately after clicking the button, but rather am waiting until they drag out a selection first. Also, your suggestion only implements what the log message was already saying to do.

Comment: Just for the record, this is the adoption for **Swift 4** (also placed in `override func awakeFromNib()`): `yourShareButtonName.sendAction(on: .leftMouseDown)`